# RestKit breaks build in archive mode - Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, restkit, archive

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 with CocoaPods 1.1.1. I've got a iOS application using RestKit 0.27, with Objective-C and Swift 3 code. Everything builds and works flawlessly in simulator and on the device, but the project won't compile when archiving it for distribution:

```
/Users/***/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h:16:9: note: in file included from /Users/***/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h:16:
#import "CustomRKObjectRequestOperation.h"
        ^
/Users/***/Services/CustomRKObjectRequestOperation.h:10:9: error: 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/***/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I found a similar issue here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/79355#79355, but suggested fix doesn't work, probably because it's for Xcode 7.1.

Comment: I ended up doing `#import "RKObjectManager.h"` style imports for each RestKit class I depend on rather than the whole <RestKit/RestKit.h> bundle. You can also try `@import RestKit;` to import the framework.

Comment: I removed all references to RestKit from the Swift part of the project (bridging header also) and the archiving fails on the very first non-Apple framework that is referenced: 

import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import Moya
import Alamofire

breaks with "No such module 'SwiftyJSON'", breaks with "No such module 'Moya'" if I put Moya as second.

Comment: I edited the run scheme to use Release configuration, the project doesn't build now. It seems the things referenced in pods don't are not available when built in Release.

Comment: Check your project's and build target's Xcode build settings to see what's different between your Debug and Release configurations. In particular check HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS in Release configuration did not have any references to any of the Pods frameworks. Everything is working fine now, nothing to do with RestKit.